# Webform: states dropdown vs textbox plain text in case of other country autoswitch?

Tags: webforms

How can I make a webform so when a user selects the country US it will show the states in a list with a mandatory select from list
and when other countries it will show Province as textedit also mandatory..
i don't want to mess arround with Jquery and hide the controls resulting into multiple fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not fond of installing a pretty big module as location, have a look at [conditional fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) which allows you to do what you need.

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition. You can, for example, define a custom “Article
>   teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is
>   checked.

So set up a select list of counties and if US is selected show the "states list" that would be hidden otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

[addressfield](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module does that perfectly.

What I don't like about it is that it will also show "address 1&2" fields. You can hide those with css.
When you output the field it will show the complete address. You can also hide the parts you don't need with css.

Comment: well this is for D7, and I'm using still the D6 :(

Comment: bummer ;-) Try the location module. There was a bug in that module when you switched countries but I heard they recently fixed it.